# ANTLR4 PLSQL Grammar Issue - Usage of Hyphen with SQL*Plus Commands

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm new to ANTLR and using ANTLR4 (4.7.2 Jar file). I'm currently working on Oracle Parser. I'm having issues with my grammar with the hyphen ('-') usage.

I am working on a project which handles scripts (includes PLSQL commands and also SQL*Plus commands). So my grammar needs to handle both the cases and parse properly. I did find some 53 commands (12.2 Oracle version).

For SQL*Plus commands, it states "You can continue a long SQL*Plus command by typing a hyphen at the end of the line and pressing Return".
One way to do this in Grammar is to send the hyphen followed by Line into a hidden channel as below.

```
WS : [ \u000B\t] -> channel(HIDDEN);    
SQLPLUS_END_WITH_HYPEN : ('-' WS* NEWLINE) -> skip;
```

But this breaks my sql grammar as hyphen followed by line is acceptable.
for eg the below should work properly.

```
Select 1 -
2 from dual;
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The docs state (emphasis mine):

> You can continue a long SQL*Plus command by typing a hyphen at the end of the line and pressing [Return]. If you wish, you can type a space before typing the hyphen. **SQL*Plus displays a right angle-bracket (>) as a prompt** for each additional line.
>
> -- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm

and also this (emphasis mine):

> **SQL*Plus is an interactive and batch query tool** that is installed with every Oracle Database installation. [...]
>
> -- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/qstart.htm#i1056581

In other words: the hyphen-line-continuation is not valid Oracle SQL. The interactive SQL*Plus tool just handles this before the SQL is interpreted/evaluated. I don't see why you'd want to handle this in a grammar.

So, if you do want to account for such occurrences in your grammar, I see no other way than to *not* skip these line continuations:

```
SQLPLUS_END_WITH_HYPHEN : ('-' NEWLINE);
```

(note that from the specs, the `-` should be directly followed by a line break/return)

And then add this `SQLPLUS_END_WITH_HYPHEN` to all of your parser rules where it could possibly occur (yes, that will be a lot). The minus sign can be handled like this:

```
expr
 : ...
 | minus expr
 | expr ( minus | PLUS ) expr
 | ...
 ;
 
minus : MINUS | SQLPLUS_END_WITH_HYPHEN;

SQLPLUS_END_WITH_HYPHEN : ('-' NEWLINE);
MINUS                   : '-';
PLUS                    : '+';
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. I am working on a project which handles scripts (includes PLSQL commands and also SQL*Plus commands). So my grammar needs to handle both the cases and parse properly. I did find some 53 commands (12.2 Oracle version).

Comment: @Sandy edited my answer. And if you're (again) going to ask how to do it in the lexer instead of the parser: my answer will be the same as the last time :)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way I can skip/ignore a token in Parser? Maybe using some override methods? (ignore the error using some try-catch block etc and continue?)

Comment: "Is there any way I can skip/ignore a token in Parser?" No.